# How to produce an array of invert ints using IntStream having a given array of ints

Tags: java, arrays

How to write a concise code transforming a given array of ints into an array consisting of inverts of numbers taken from the first array:

```
[1, 2, 4, ...] -> [1.0, 0.5, 0.25, ...]
```

I found streams (such as IntStream, DoubleStream) useful and I would like to use them, but I am not able to deal with types (Int -> Double).

I am able to deal with similar problem but for functions transforming ints into ints: below is code for a function `x->10x+1` instead of `x->1/x`:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> 10*i+1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is it possible to find something analogous for x->1/x or another "complicated" function such as `exp()` or `ln()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IntStream.mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction-):

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToDouble(i -> 1.0 / i /* or whatever */)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```